# How to resolve the location rquired sample.fxml

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to launch the sample.fxml file in the main class but an error is occured telling me:

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.**

my project structure :
[image]

my main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

my sample.fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane style="-fx-backround-color:#33d9b2;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="sample.Controller"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0">
<TableView style="-fx-backround-color:#33d9b2;" fx:id="produits" prefWidth="600" prefHeight="290">

    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>

    </columnResizePolicy>
    <columns>

        <TableColumn text="matricule" style="-fx-backround-color:#33d9b2">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="matricule"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Produit name">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="produitName"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: the lookup path is a _package_ - either relative or absolute (see the api doc of class.getResource). From your picture, the sample.fxml that's in the same package as Main should be found by your relative lookup, the sample.fxml under the resources will not (because they are in the default package, accessible by absolute path only). So something wrong that you are not showing .. check which is copied into the output path (the location where you find the Main.class)

Comment: i've found the solution i had to move my resrouces folder into my main folder

Comment: not necessarily: you could have a parallel path structure under resources ..